# How to capture tap event on specific button in user control from main form

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling

I have a windows store app that has a main form and several user controls. In each user control, I have an image, that, when tapped, should trigger a storyboard animation setup outside of the user control.

The storyboard to fade the user control IN, works fine, but obviously I need the fade OUT animation to fire when the close button is clicked within the user control.

Here's the code I added to the user control itself to fire when the close button is clicked. The problem is that it's firing when you click *anywhere* on the usercontrol, not just the close button.

```
public sealed partial class Page02 : UserControl {

    public delegate void CloseButtonTappedHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e);
    public event CloseButtonTappedHandler CloseButtonTapped;

    public Page02() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.imgCloseButton.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(this.imgCloseButton_Tapped);
    }

    private void imgCloseButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (CloseButtonTapped != null) {
            CloseButtonTapped(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The main page code looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AddHandler(UIElement.TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Page02_CloseButtonTapped), true);

    }

    private void textBlock1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        MenuBar01.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        HideUserControl1.Begin();
        ShowUserControl2.Begin();
    }

    private void Page02_CloseButtonTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        HideUserControl2.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: please include your XAML as well

Comment: <Image x:Name="imgCloseButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Margin="1714,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Source="Assets/CloseButton.png" Tapped="imgCloseButton_Tapped"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
this.AddHandler(UIElement.TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Page02_CloseButtonTapped), true);
```

is associating the tapped event of the MainPage to Page02_CloseButtonTapped method. So any tap event on it will fire the method.

I'm assuming you meant to attach it to the CloseButtonTapped event on the Page02 control instead?

Comment: yes, I need it attached to the specific control "imgCloseButton" inside the user control.

Comment: But the main form needs to be the one that's aware of the event so that it can fade the user control out when that button is clicked

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Instead of the line that he mentions, you want to change it to Page02.CloseButtonTapped += ...    -- replace Page02 with whatever the page name is.  This will hook to your event, not create a new handler for one.

Comment: @oppassum, can you check out my new problem related this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480998/capturing-multiple-tap-events-on-a-usercontrol-from-a-main-form-xaml