# Capturing _multiple_ tap events on a usercontrol from a main form (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

In reference to this question that was answered yesterday:

[How to capture tap event on specific button in user control from main form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455961/how-to-capture-tap-event-on-specific-button-in-user-control-from-main-form)

I am now facing the issue where I have a "dashboard" usercontrol, so now I have to add multiple tap events to the same user control.

What's happening though is it seems that only the first tap event is firing.

Help?

(page 03 is the one in question)

mainform:

```
public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        Page02.CloseButtonTapped += Page02_CloseButtonTapped;
        Page03.CloseButtonTapped += Page03_CloseButtonTapped;
        Page11.CloseButtonTapped += Page11_CloseButtonTapped;

        Page03.CommandControlTapped += Page03_CommandControlTapped;

    }
```

page03:

```
public delegate void CloseButtonTappedHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e);
public delegate void CommandControlTappedHandler(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e);

public sealed partial class Page03 : UserControl {
    public event CloseButtonTappedHandler CloseButtonTapped;
    public event CommandControlTappedHandler CommandControlTapped;

    public Page03() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.imgCloseButton.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(this.imgCloseButton_Tapped);
        this.imgTraining.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(this.imgTraining_Tapped);
        this.imgCommandControl.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(this.imgCommandControl_Tapped);
    }

    private void imgCloseButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (CloseButtonTapped != null) {
            CloseButtonTapped(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void imgCommandControl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (CommandControlTapped != null) {
            CommandControlTapped(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void imgTraining_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (CommandControlTapped != null) {
            CommandControlTapped(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Page03 User Control XAML: (there's a bunch of layout stuff in there, line shapes, etc)

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Raytheon.Page03"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Raytheon"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="918"
d:DesignWidth="1818" Background="Gray">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="625,416,0,0" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="557" Opacity="0.5">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1457.34" Margin="896.467,-53.724,0,-485.616" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1457.345" Margin="896.467,-523.224,0,-16.121" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="478" Margin="396,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="665,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" Source="Assets/1920x1080_TailoredSolutions.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="126,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_Training.png"/>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="506.55,325.193,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="478" Margin="1402,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="1291.55,325.193,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" ScaleX="-1"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="1076,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="1076,466,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="731,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="731,466,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" Opacity="0.5" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.85"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Image x:Name="imgCloseButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="1669,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Source="Assets/CloseButton.png" Tapped="imgCloseButton_Tapped"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtSustainment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="439,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_Sustainment.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtCommunicaton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="1134,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_Communications.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtFixedSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="1438,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_FixedSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtPhysicalSecurity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="1438,775,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="270" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_PhysicalSecurity.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtPlatformUpgrades" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="1132,773,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_PlatformUpgrades.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtDataAnalytics" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="783,773,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_DataAnalytics.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtDistributedSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="439,763,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_DistributedSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtMobileSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="126,763,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_MobileSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="txtCommandControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="783,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Text_CommandControl.png"/>

    <Image x:Name="imgTraining" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="128,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_Training.png" Tapped="imgTraining_Tapped"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgSustainment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="441,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_Sustainment.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgCommunications" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="1136,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_Communications.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgMobileSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="128,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_MobileSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgDistributedSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="441,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_DistributedSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgDataAnalytics" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="785,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_DataAnalytics.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgPlatformUpgrades" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="1136,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_PlatformUpgrades.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgFixedSensors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="1440,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_FixedSensors.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgPhysicalSecurity" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="1440,561,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_PhysicalSecurity.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgCommandControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" Margin="785,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_CommandControl.png"  Tapped="imgCommandControl_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Super stuck here folks. @oppassum, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for the events on Page03 individually in the MainPage and not create new handlers for them. See below

```
Page03.CloseButtonTapped += MethodToHandleEvent
Page03.Page11Tapped += MethodToHandleEvent
```

The lines calling AddHandler, are registering new handlers for the events and I think this is causing you some confusion. You may want to read up a bit more about events here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Interesting. I went like this:  

    `Page02.CloseButtonTapped += Page02_CloseButtonTapped;
    Page03.CloseButtonTapped += Page03_CloseButtonTapped;
    Page11.CloseButtonTapped += Page11_CloseButtonTapped;

    Page03.Page11Tapped += imgCommandControl_Tapped;`

but only the close button events are firing.

Comment: I even just tried attaching a message box event to that image without bubbling anything up to the main form and it's not firing, so now I'm very confused :)

Comment: Are you sure the Page11Tapped event is firing from the Page03 control? You should debug and check that it is firing correctly from Page03 and then check that it is being handled correctly in MainPage.

Comment: no it's not firing at all. I added a breakpoint and nothing's happening when I tap the image. I have no idea why. `<Image x:Name="imgCommandControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="224" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Icon_CommandControl.png" Tapped="imgCommandControl_Tapped" Margin="785,94,0,0"/>

Comment: private void imgCommandControl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (imgCommandControlTapped != null) {
                imgCommandControlTapped(sender, e);
            }
        }

Comment: But here's the weird thing. If I attach the imgCommandControl_Tapped event to the close button, it fires the event properly and shows the other screen properly. So for some reason, these other images are completely ignoring the tapped event.

Comment: Can't really tell much without seeing all the code but you could simple wrap the image in a button control as shown here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/629/

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. What code can I show you to help you help me? I'm at a loss as to why the close button image fires fine, but this other image does not.

Comment: can you add the all XAML for Page03 and the all code behind to the question?

Comment: I just updated the "main form" Code as well for reference

Comment: I noticed there isn't a specific event for imgTraining and you are reusing the CommandControlTapped  event. Should there be a 3rd event which you fire instead of firing the CommandControlTapped event again?

Comment: that was just to see if it was that specific command and control image not working, so I attached the same event to see if either image would fire it. Again note that the "close" button image works fine and will call the command and control event no problem. They're all images, there's nothing special about them. I even tried to remove the close event all together in case it was some order of operations thing.. no luck.

Comment: any further ideas? Still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because how I'm showing/hiding the user controls is via changing the opacity:

```
<local:Page01 Margin="53,156,8,10" x:Name="Page01" />
    <local:Page02 Margin="53,156,8,30" x:Name="Page02" Opacity="0"/>
    <local:Page11 Margin="53,156,8,30" x:Name="Page11" Opacity="0"/>
    <local:Page03 Margin="53,156,8,30" x:Name="Page03" Opacity="0"/>
```

so I swapped the order of page 11 and page 3, and it started working. So now becomes the task of having to show/hide the user controls while retaining the storyboard animation, but not having them actually just "hidden" vs actually making them visible/collapsed.

Comment: Great that you solved the issue. I would suggest that you look into Canvas.ZIndex in order to ensure the order is correct. See here for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2006/06/13/controlling-z-order-using-the-zindex-property/